# aggregating within multiindex dataframe pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I am looking for help relating to this multiindex dataframe

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

array = [np.array(['jan','jan','feb','feb','mar','mar']), np.array(['food','rent','food','rent','food','rent'])]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,high=100,size=(6,1)),index=array,columns=['expense'])
```

i am trying to sum up the amounts for 'food' and 'rent' across the entire dataframe - what is the simplest way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `groupby` index level (`food` and `rent` are at level 1 index):

```
df.groupby(level=1).sum()

#      expense
#food      166
#rent      161
```

Comment: or `df.sum(level=1)` ?